# Using VSC commands from terminal

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal

Is it possible to call VSC commands (the ones you enter after pressing SHIFT-CMD-P) from the terminal?
Like selecting a certain view in the activity bar and so on…

Comment: Do you mean you want to type out the VS Code command palette commands  (ie. commands you type after pressing Shift + Cmd + P, like "Developer: Reload Window" and "Add Line Comment") inside the integrated terminal and execute them? If that's what you mean, the answer is NO.

Comment: Yup, that's what I was looking for. Too bad, but thanks for the quick reply.